# C++ lambda remove elements from set of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, set

I have the following set

```
    //Create a set which orders the elements according to their size.
    auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
    {
        if (a.size() < b.size())
            return true;
        if (a.size() > b.size())
            return false;
        return a < b;
    };
    auto path = std::set <vector<int>, decltype(comp)> (comp);
```

and the following vector.

```
vector<int> nodePath;
```

and I'd like to remove all the elements of the set which size is bigger than the size of the nodePath vector.

```
path.erase(std::remove_if(path.begin(), path.end(),
[](vector<int> task) { return task.size()>nodePath.size(); }), path.end());
```

When I execute the program like this he throws:

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:347:93: error: ‘nodePath’ is not captured
                         [](vector<int> task) { return task.size()>nodePath.size(); }), path.end());
                                                                   ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:347:52: note: the lambda has no capture-default
                                                   [](vector<int> task) { return task.size()>nodePath.size(); }), path.end());
                                                    ^
main.cpp:285:29: note: ‘std::vector<int> nodePath’ declared here
                 vector<int> nodePath;
```

If I put the nodePath vector in the [] he will throw:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_ForwardIterator std::__remove_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Predicate) [with _ForwardIterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::vector<int> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<run(int*, char***)::<lambda(std::vector<int>)> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/bits/stl_algo.h:936:30:   required from ‘_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::vector<int> >; _Predicate = run(int*, char***)::<lambda(std::vector<int>)>]’
main.cpp:347:119:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/bits/stl_algo.h:868:16: error: passing ‘const std::vector<int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
      *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::remove_if()` cannot be used with a set.

The only way to remove values from a set is with its `erase()` method.

`std::remove_if()` removes values from a sequence by literally copying them, and returning the ending iterator value of the new sequence. You do call `erase()`, using the ending iterator value, but this is not enough.

`std::remove_if()` is meant to be used with sequence containers, like `std::vector` or `std::list`, where you can remove individual elements simply by copying over them. But this does not work with a `std::set()`, because `std::remove_if()` knows nothing about the set's `erase()` method, the only way to remove values from a set.

You will need to write your own code to iterate over the set, correctly, and remove the values that you want to remove.

Watch out for the most frequent pitfall: after removing an element from a set, the iterator you just removed is no longer valid.

Comment: I ran in exactly that pitfall with

for(vector<int> task: path)
{
      if(task.size()>nodePath.size())
          {
                 path.erase(task);
           }
 }

Comment: Copy the iterator first, advance the iterator to the next element in the container, and only then delete the value, using the copy.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can't you just use the iterator returned by the `erase` function?

Comment: It is not safe to remove elements from a container while using a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate through it.

Comment: for(set<vector<int>>::iterator iter = path.begin(); iter != path.end();)
                    {
                        if((*iter).size()>nodePath.size())
                        {
                            path.erase(iter++);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ++iter;
                        }
                    }
Solved it